# refresh same screen with different data ios app

Tags: ios

I am creating a simple app in which we want to ask 10 different questions with 4 options to users.

So when app loads, the screen has 1 question, 4 options, a background image and go button.

I have stored all these 10 questions with their options and background image in multidimensional array.

When I click on go button I want to refresh same screen and want to show next question with their options and background image.

And also when I go back.

I am very new to iOS, what approach should I take for achieving this?

Can it be possible using single screen or I have to make multiple screens.

Any idea? Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest, take single view only, and your button press `IBAction`, update the text of the question and answer labels/textfields

Answer (score 0):

On Your viewDidLoad or the like add this

```
[ButtonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonOne) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ButtonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonTwo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ButtonThree addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonThree) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ButtonFour addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonFour) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The start is the button name and the selector is essential the method you want to run when the button is clicked on.

What I'm going to do now is make an integer for each question. This integer will determine whether the question is right or wrong. So depending on the question the integer will be assigned to the button number e.g. if button 2 is right the integer will be assigned to 2 for that particular question. Im also going to use a second integer to find out what question the user is on.

```
int QuestionNumber;
int Right[11];
Right[1] = *What ever the right button for question 1 is*
....
Right[10] = *What ever the right button for question 10 is*
```

I'm now going to create the method for each button. Please note I'll only be doing it for 1 of the buttons as the rest are really just the same.

```
-(void)ButtonOne
{
    switch (QuestionNumber) {
        case 1:
            if (Right[1] == 1) { //Change the Right[] number depending on question and change the == (1) depending on the button
                NSLog(@"Correct Answer");

                [ButtonOne setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [ButtonTwo setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [ButtonThree setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [ButtonFour setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                Label.text = @"NEXT QUESTION";
                BackGround.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
                QuestionNumber++;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Got Question wrong");
                //Do whatever you want if question is wrong
            }
            break;
            ....
        case 10:
            if (Right[10] == 1) {
                NSLog(@"Correct Answer");

                [ButtonOne setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [ButtonTwo setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [ButtonThree setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [ButtonFour setTitle:@"ANSWER TO OTHER QUESTION" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                Label.text = @"NEXT QUESTION";
                BackGround.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Got Question wrong");
                //Do whatever you want if question is wrong
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Now what that is doing is if you get a question right it automatically moves onto the next question. If you want to go back, simply add a button and have: `QuestionNumber = QuestionNumber -1;` And as of course again on that button have a switch statement to find out what should be displayed.

If you're new I would recommend you watch this youtube series as it'll help you.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJy7fero79U&list=PLrL5aCF7Ods_21oym4X-XJUWgj34MFTHi)